What is the best approach to handle a burger menu in 2024 considering accessibility and semantic HTML?
I'm exploring the best way to implement a responsive burger menu in 2024, taking into account the latest advancements in CSS and accessibility standards. Here’s what I’ve analyzed so far:
CSS-only approach:
With the :has() selector, it is now possible to simulate interactivity by using a checked <input> (e.g., checkbox). This allows creating a fully functional burger menu without relying on JavaScript.
However, this method introduces form elements into the HTML purely for styling purposes, which may pollute the markup and potentially confuse assistive technologies like screen readers.
JavaScript approach:
By using JavaScript, we can detect clicks on interactive elements (e.g., buttons) and toggle classes on the menu, avoiding the need for form elements altogether.
This method could improve semantic clarity and might align better with accessibility standards, but it involves additional scripting.
My requirements are:

Accessibility: Ensure the solution is fully compatible with screen
readers and other assistive technologies.
Semantic HTML: The markup should be clean and meaningful, avoiding unnecessary elements.
Browser support: The solution should work reliably across modern browsers in 2024. Performance: Lightweight and efficient implementation is preferred.

Could you recommend a solution that offers the best balance between these requirements ? I'm also open to alternative approaches that I might not have
considered.

I'm confused as to what you're looking for. A library? It sounds like you're asking for code not software. Not sure what a checkbox has to do with a hamburger menu either, just marking the open status? That doesn't sound too modern.

Asking for best is asking for opinions

Yes, I'm asking about the best approaches when it comes to coding.
